# Font size not changing after resetting default css values?

Tags: html, css

I reset the default css values first and declared some font-size.After that I wanted to update the font-size to some other value its not working..

```
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;font-size: 18px;}  /*reset*/

/* Styling links */

#styling-links{
    background: #333;
}

#styling-links #container{
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace ;
    font-size: 2em; /*not working*/
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Add a comma b/w #styling-links and #container ie '#styling-links,#container'

Comment: Don’t specify a font-size for `*`, that is a dumb idea. Your code successfully sets a font-size of 2em for the element `#styling-links #container` - but any descendant elements inside that will of course get their font-size from the `*` rule again.

Comment: Yeah that worked but doesn't the #styling-links #container override '*' command?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma between the element Ids, Use this instead: `#styling-links, #container{`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
#styling-links, #container{
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace ;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
}
```